# How to use i2c_gpio with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, i2c, device-tree

I would like to use the i2c_gpio software i2c kernel module because the broadcom hardware i2c does not support I2C_M_NOSTART. How do I do this?

I think that in order to do it I need to take [the device tree config for i2c_gpio](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/i2c/i2c-gpio.txt) and turn it into a device tree fragment, then [compile and load it.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) But I don't know how to rewrite the config as a fragment. Perhaps there is another, easier way.

Comment: Have you actually compiled and tried to use `i2c-gpio.ko`?  It seems to build pretty easily.

Comment: i2c-gpio is already built in the standard kernel modules. My question is how do you make it work? Loading it won't do anything without a configuration.

Comment: Are you sure?  It's not set in `bcmrpi_defconfig`, which is usually identical to the one spit out via proc from [this kernel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot).  Try `modprobe configs; gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep I2C_GPIO`.  You probably get `# CONFIG_I2C_GPIO is not set`.  Not that that helps much with using it, but you are one step closer.  Or further away, lol.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's not in the default modules on raspbian. One more thing I need to sort out.

Comment: Okay I have rebuilt the kernel with the module. As I expected it does absolutely nothing when loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As of June 2016 Raspbian already has the necessary modifications. You only need to enable the overlay in config.txt (step 6 onwards).**

I finally got this working as follows:

1. [Rebuild the kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) with i2c_gpio module.
   You must edit the bcm2708_defconfig or bcmrpi_defconfig and add the line `CONFIG_I2C_GPIO=m` before running the `make defconfig`.
2. Install kernel and modules using mkknlimg for device tree support as described in the kernel building docs.
3. Convert the example i2c_gpio config to a device tree fragment as follows:

   ```
   // Overlay for i2c_gpio bitbanging host bus.
   /dts-v1/;
   /plugin/;

   / {
           compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

           fragment@0 {
                   target-path = "/";
                   __overlay__ {
                           i2c_gpio: i2c@0 {
                                   compatible = "i2c-gpio";
                                   gpios = <&gpio 23 0 /* sda */
                                            &gpio 24 0 /* scl */
                                           >;
                                   i2c-gpio,delay-us = <2>; /* ~100 kHz */
                                   #address-cells = <1>;
                                   #size-cells = <0>;
                           };
                   };
           };
           __overrides__ {
                   i2c_gpio_sda = <&i2c_gpio>,"gpios:4";
                   i2c_gpio_scl = <&i2c_gpio>,"gpios:16";
                   i2c_gpio_delay_us = <&i2c_gpio>,"i2c-gpio,delay-us:0";
           };
   };
   ```

   - This will default to using gpio 23 and 24 for software i2c.
   - delay-us should be 2 for 100kHz operation.
   - The following lines should be removed because they will prevent the driver from working on Raspberry Pi:
             `i2c-gpio,sda-open-drain;`
             `i2c-gpio,scl-open-drain;`
4. Build the device tree blob with `dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o i2c-gpio.dtb i2c-gpio.dts`
5. Copy the blob to /boot/overlays/
6. Add a line in /boot/config.txt `dtoverlay=i2c-gpio`

   If you want to use different pins, put `dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=<pin>,i2c_gpio_scl=<pin>` instead. You can also change the rate with `i2c_gpio_delay_us=<usecs>`.
7. Reboot.
8. `modprobe i2c-dev` and you now should have /dev/i2c-3 in addition to any others you previously configured.

Comment: Good job.  Could you edit your answer to clarify which line is the "open drain" one?  As a matter of record you should be able to achieve the same I2C commands with my http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bbI2CZip function.

Comment: Updated. I didn't know pigpio had that feature. I'm already using piscope and I2C_sniffer.py to watch the bus activity. It looks like I will need a user space implementation anyway because even i2c-gpio can't quite work with the buggy i2c device I am trying to control.

Comment: It looks like Raspbian circa August 2016 has all of the tough work done as "i2c-gpio" is installed already. Steps 6-8 are really all that seem to be needed.